# How to use variables of run method in other methods of a process class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

How to use a variable(Complex Object) created inside **'run'** method in other methods of the Process class?

I understood the scope of variables created or modified inside run method is limited within itself, but is there any way to crack this ?

This is my sample code,

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class DummyCls:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Hii"

class MyProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.my_object = None

    def run(self):
        self.my_object = DummyCls()
        self.my_object.name = "Hello"

    def get_name(self):
        print(self.my_object.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_process = MyProcess()
    my_process.start()
    my_process.get_name()
    my_process.join()
```

I'm getting error stating that,

> print(self.my_object.name)
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Answer (score 2):

`my_process.my_object` is never instantiated, because `my_process.run()` is never called.

One way to fix it would be to add the following to your `if __name == '__main__'`:

```
my_process = MyProcess()
my_process.start()
my_process.run()  # new
my_process.get_name()
my_process.join()
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, But it won't work as i expected. run will executed automatically no need to call it. If i call the run method explicitly, the run method will execute twice. One is implicit run(in separate process). And the other one is the explicit run call (that you hv mentioned) will execute in the same process(i can't use multiprocessing feature in this case).